# Python и pyttsx3 как служба

Tags: python, windows, service, pyttsx3, tts

есть задача: оффлайн синтезирование речи, с получением текста для синтеза от Flask и запуском всего этого в качестве службы. 
Работает так: Запускаем скрипт, открываем страницу localhost:8080, пишем текст, нажимаем отправить ... Profit.

Все отлично работало, пока я не пришел к моменту, когда все это нужно запускать как службу или как задачу планировщика Windows (с параметром "**Выполнять для всех пользователей**" и триггером "**При запуске компьютера**").

Я пробовал и изощрялся по всякому, компилировал в EXE, использовал разные настройки, использовал import logging, чтобы поймать неуловимую ошибку, ничего мне не дало наводку, куда копать, единственное предположение, это отсутствие доступа к аудиоустройству для скрипта.

Если кто-нибудь знает, как запустить этот тестовый код из планировщика Windows (через bat файл с кодом `python C:\script.py`) с указанными выше параметрами, я **умоляю** не проходите мимо.

Сведенный к минимуму код, который потребует только установки pyttsx3 и pywin32:

script.py

```
import pyttsx3

engine = pyttsx3.init()
voices = engine.getProperty('voices') 
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[0].id)
engine.say('OK')
engine.runAndWait()
engine.stop()
```

С удовольствием прочитаю про альтернативные варианты решения этой проблемы или объяснения, почему это не работает.

Comment: Тебе в планировщик или как службу?

Comment: Я нашел решение этой проблемы, возможно не самое правильное, но это работает (код ниже). Сейчас запустил как задачу планировщика, но я почти уверен, что это сработает и для службы. Но я так и не понял, почему это не работало с примером выше.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def say (text,rate=180,vol=1.0,vid=0): #say text, rate - speed, vol - volume, vid - select voice
    soundFile = dir+'\\sound\\'+datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%H_%M_%S")+'.wav'
    engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5') 
    engine.setProperty('rate', rate)     
    engine.setProperty('volume',vol)    
    voices = engine.getProperty('voices')       
    engine.setProperty('voice', voices[vid].id)
    engine.save_to_file(text,soundFile)
    engine.runAndWait()
    engine.stop()

    playsound.playsound(soundFile, True)
```